# Loading the same ViewController after watching MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a ViewController which displays the information about the selected show, and the play button of the MPMoviePlayerController is there. Now, the issue is when I clicked on the full screen of the player then clicked done. It is supposed to go back to the ViewController which displays the info, but it isn't. But it is going in to the viewDidLoad of the ViewController and it doesn't display anything at all. I feel like something is on the top of the ViewController or something like that

Here's how I remove the player controller

```
- (void)dealloc
{
self.delegate = nil;
self.activityIndicator = nil;
[self deregisterMoviePlayerNotifications];
[self.player.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromSuperview];
[self stopVideo];
self.player = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AVPlayerViewController` as `MPMoviePlayerController` is deprecated. You can use this code on play button

```
-(void)playButton{    
    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:urlVideo];
    AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    controller.player = player;
    controller.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:player.currentItem];
    controller.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    [player play];
}

-(void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification*)notification{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Note : Don't forget to add `AVFoundation.framework`.